# Heroku EU region how to setup custom domain name?

Tags: heroku

Heroku EU region how to setup custom domain name?

I have tried to setup 3 arecords that point to heroku server.

```
174.129.212.2
75.101.145.87   
75.101.163.44
```

I have added the domain to the app. But when visiting the domain it says no such app..

I have pinged the heroku app domain. (myap.heroku.com) and setup an arecord with it (the ip). And it still says no such app..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use IP addresses with Heroku Europe - only CNAME's will work (or are the only supported mechanism). You simply CNAME your custom domain to myapp.herokuapp.com in your DNS control panel, add the custom domain to your application via the CLI or heroku.com and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to point an A/AAAA Record to Heroku Europe Apps.

Just add the domain (most likely root domain and www-subdomain) to your domains in the Heroku Settings of your app.

Then ping your example.herokuapp.com domain in the console e.g.

ping example.herokuapp.com

Use the IP you get through the ping as your A/AAAA Record target.

Worked very well for me, zero costs.