# Heroku SSL addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku

I've successfully provisioned an SSL certificate for my subdomain.
I've added the SSL addon as per the instructions provided by heroku.

```
$ heroku certs:add be_different_democrat.crt be.different.democrat.key 
Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL Endpoint to limitless-anchorage-7146... done
limitless-anchorage-7146 now served by mie-7562.herokussl.com
Certificate details:
Common Name(s): be.different.democrat
                www.be.different.democrat

Expires At:     2014-08-23 23:59 UTC
Issuer:         /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Free SSL/CN=be.different.democrat
Starts At:      2014-05-25 00:00 UTC
Subject:        /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Free SSL/CN=be.different.democrat
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

The next step is to reconfigure my `CNAME` record to point at the SSL endpoint, https://mie-7562.herokussl.com/

If I visit that URL I can see my certificate is installed, but my app fails to load. So I'd rather not repoint my `CNAME`

```
$ heroku certs
Endpoint                Common Name(s)                                    Expires               Trusted
----------------------  ------------------------------------------------  --------------------  -------
mie-7562.herokussl.com  be.different.democrat, www.be.different.democrat  2014-08-23 23:59 UTC  True
```

Any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: i have answered such type of question in detail long ago, check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400672/how-to-point-a-domain-at-a-heroku-application may be it helps

Comment: Thanks @ParitoshPiplewar but I think you're missing the point I've added my domain http://be.different.democrat to the app and it works, I've added SSL but my app isn't being served from the SSL endpoint so I'm reluctant to repoint the domain

Comment: You can't access the SSL point directly to access your site. You need to update your DNS to point the CNAME at the SSL endpoint. Your SSL request is terminated at the SSL endpoint at which point its forwarded to your application - if you access your SSL url directly it will show 'no such application'.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity @JohnBeynon working now :)